# Unable to weight paint the "knee" area of my character?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, weight-painting, vertex-weights

So I have 'Add' selected on the weight paint and when I try adding weight to the knee on my characters legs it wont add anything no matter how many times I click or how I adjust the strength. It will only add weight if I click in very specific parts of the mesh not near the knee at all more towards the bottom or the top.

Im not sure if this is a problem with the mesh itself or the weight paint?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It's hard to tell from this screenshot only why it doesn't work. Keep in mind that you only can weight-paint the vertices. If the mesh is fairly low-poly then it's normal that you cannot paint in the middle of the face area where no vertices are. Turn on the *Wireframe* overlay so you can see the vertices in weight paint mode. One more thing: for animation, you want to generate the Rigify rig from the metarig and parent the mesh to it ("rig") and not to the metarig.

Comment: @moonboots just shared it sorry i thought i did earlier

Comment: @Blunder okay thank you i just added a loop cut near the knee and it fixed the issue, always did have trouble rigging low poly models but they are the only models i can do good haha